# Linear regression plot is not showing complete equation below chart R

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a linear model with the help of Plot function in R. 
I am facing a problem that complete equation is not coming below the chart.

Complete Equation is

```
lm(log(ExpensePerMember) ~ log(IncomePerMember) + BranchCluster +
   log(TotalMember) + RentFlag, data = CompleteDetail7)
```

but I am not getting same in below chart equation.  I have tried zooming, exporting through equation and exporting through export button in R. Please suggest if there is an option to do this.

The formula used for plotting the graph is plot(lmmodel20)

[image: plot]

Comment: Do you mean the label by "complete equation is not coming below the chart"?  And as always: please try to make your example reproducible!

Comment: @Manuel S I mean the labelled equation.

Comment: Do you mean the texts in bottom of your figure which gets cut out and only ends as "+ log(Total ..." ?

Comment: Why do you care? This is just a diagnostics plot. If you need a plot for publication you should probably design your own plot anyway.

Comment: @zyurnaidi yes this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add a mtext with cex<1

```
plot( c$fitted,c$residuals,xlab="",     main = "Residuals vs Fitted"     )
mtext("log(ExpensePerMember) ~ log(IncomePerMember) + BranchCluster +log(TotalMember) + RentFlag", side=1, line=2.2, cex=0.8)
```

Comment: Thanks it did my job, though still I am getting the predefined text in my graph. How to remove them, any idea?

Comment: use xlab="" not xlab=NULL, my bad!